# Getting error while trying to install ngrx in Angular application

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to install ngrx in my Angular application. I have executed the command

> ng add @ngrx/store@latest

But it results in an error as follows

## npm resolution error report

2022-07-07T20:36:16.089Z

While resolving: crudapp@0.0.0
Found: @angular/core@13.3.11
node_modules/@angular/core
@angular/core@"~13.3.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/core@"^14.0.0" from @ngrx/store@14.0.1
node_modules/@ngrx/store
@ngrx/store@"14.0.1" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

```
{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "@angular/core",
    "version": "13.3.11",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "crudapp",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "path": "/home/Projects/Learning/Angular-ngrx-CRUD/angular-ngrx-crud"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/@angular/core",
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "@angular/core",
        "spec": "~13.3.0",
        "from": {
          "location": "/home/Projects/Learning/Angular-ngrx-CRUD/angular-ngrx-crud"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "@angular/core",
    "spec": "^14.0.0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "@ngrx/store",
      "version": "14.0.1",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "crudapp",
        "version": "0.0.0",
        "path": "/home/Projects/Learning/Angular-ngrx-CRUD/angular-ngrx-crud"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/@ngrx/store",
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "@ngrx/store",
          "spec": "14.0.1",
          "from": {
            "location": "/home/Projects/Learning/Angular-ngrx-CRUD/angular-ngrx-crud"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "peerConflict": null,
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

Can anyone have any idea about the same? I have tried with some angular version updations and all. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is there is a different version of angular and ngrx/store, your project uses angular 13, and the ngrx/store trying to find angular 14 because you are using command @latest. The solution is you can try to use ng add @ngrx/store@13

Comment: The issue is getting worst when I try to install the rest dependencies of ngrx. We need to specifically mention the exact version.